# How to check Kurento media server traffic

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc, kurento, kurento-media-server

Can you tell me how to check Kurento media server traffic?

I can't find it no matter how much I search.

Help me plesae. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using machine network metrics? Why do you need the value from Kurento itself?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/257263/how-to-display-network-traffic-in-the-terminal

Comment: Sorry i don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean that you can check server traffic instead of getting metrics from Kurento.

Comment: I checked the traffic on the server with Ubuntu, but nothing changed.

Comment: What do you mean nothing changed? Do you have some problem you are trying to resolve? Please elaborate what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, so I checked the Ubuntu traffic and there was no change. I'm using a media server, so the traffic has to change...ㅠㅠ Is there a wrong way to check traffic?

Comment: Where are media server clients located? On others machines?

Comment: Thanks for your help first. I am using an Amazon ec2 instance, the Kurento media server and media server client exist in different ec2 instances.

Comment: Ok, not sure why the traffic is not visible.

Comment: Here are some tools that may help you

Comment: Here are some tools that may help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/257263/how-to-display-network-traffic-in-the-terminal

Comment: Thank you so much! Server traffic can now be checked:)

Comment: You are welcome  Don't forget accepting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I just clicked the arrow, was the answer accepted?